# Suddenly can't boot

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, partition, data-recovery, internet-recovery

I was using my 13 inch Macbook Pro (mid 2012) as normal when it suddenly became really slow and it became so unresponsive I just forced it to shutdown by holding down the power button. After that I couldn't boot it off of any partition as there was a question mark folder on boot.

I launched the latest version of internet recovery mode by using option-command-r while restarting the computer. After that I used the Terminal and typed
`diskutil list /dev/disk0` and got:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *525.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         524.9 GB   disk0s2
```

followed by `diskutil info /dev/disk0` with output:

```
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       Crucial_CT525MX300SSD1

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  SATA
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 525.1 GB (525112713216 Bytes) (exactly 1025610768 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No
```

followed by `fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0` and got:

```
** Checking the container superblock.
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 203
warning: container has been mounted by APFS version 1412.141.3.7.2, which is newer than 1412.141.1
warning: disabling overallocation repairs by default; use -o to override
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager
error: (oid 0x30d62) cib: invalid o_cksum (0x0)
error: failed to read spaceman cib 0x30d62
   Space manager is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk0 could not be verified completely.
```

after which I used `fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0s2` and got the exact same output.

I notice the space manager is invalid, but is that the cause of my unbootable partition/drive? If yes, how do I solve it? If no, what could it be?

Comment: The internal drive has failed. That model is old enough that you have the option of replacing it.

Comment: Try to repair it -- Repair the disk by booting from the Recovery HD. Immediately after the chime hold down the Command and R keys until the Utility Menu appears. Choose Disk Utility and click on the Continue button. Select the indented (usually, Macintosh HD) volume entry from the side list.  Click on the First Aid button in the toolbar. Wait for the Done button to appear. Quit Disk Utility and return to the Utility Menu. Restart the computer from the Apple Menu.

Comment: I can't repair it because when I use the FirstAid inside the Disk Utility tool it can't verify any errors.

Answer (score 1):

As Linc D. commented, the drive has failed, but it wasn't the only problem.
The second problem was the HDD cable that was faulty.

Comment: How does one tell that the cable is faulty?

Comment: I took out the faulty SSD, inserted a perfect one that was recognised while being used as an external one, but this time I used the perfect one as an internal drive but it wasn't recognised. I also did the same thing with the faulty drive. The faulty one wasn't recognised when used as an internal drive, but it was recognised while being used as an external drive.